# database connection: protocoling data for hundereds to million objects

Tags: java, python, mysql, database, oop

I am running economic simulations. hundreds or thousands of agents  = objects have to protocol data over time, the data has always the same structure. It typically is composed from a number of Booleans, floats and integers, possibly arrays/list (between 5 and 100 different variables). During the simulation the database has no read access. After the simulation the data will not be changed anymore. For every simulation I will create a new database. The current programming-languages are java for one project and python for a second. Its also possible that in the future the project is run on a network. If it matters: the objects communicate via 0mq. We are using mySql and sqllight.

How do I connect the thousands of objects to the database. The end result should be all be in one database.

/currently we send the data via zeromq messaging to one object that writes into the database.

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: I can't open thousands of connections to the database. Is pooling all in one object that writes to the database the best solution? How would you design it?

Comment: Your ZeroMQ solution does not sound unreasonable; I might use some other RPC mechanism (but that's subjective). Perhaps this question would be better on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you use python (and you're okay with storing the data in non-sql format), I would recommend the object database called [ZODB](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/) (by zope). Essentially, you'll be creating a dictionary (which can contain literally any data type you want). I use this for my own research and it has been great. There's also a fairly reasonable learning curve, meaning it won't take you more than a few days to really master it.

Since you mention that during your simulation the database "has no read access" you can use ZODB as a standalone tool. However, if you find yourself running multiple simulations in parallel (say multithreading or cloud computing), you will have to look into [ZEO](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/documentation/guide/zeo.html) (also by zope) in order to make this a solution.

Each one of your simulations need not be it's own database with ZODB, it can be a separate key of a single "simulation" database, where the data for each run will be neatly nested underneath each key. You'll be able to say something like: `print Simulation['run99']['output']` just as easily as you would with say the 98th run of your simulation.